Cannot find the XML Schema file for Office Open XML Extensions
In one of the schemas of Office Open XML Schema Extensions there's a link to external xlbasictypes.xsd schema file:
<xsd:import schemaLocation="xlbasictypes.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" />

However, I could not find this schema file. Does anyone know where to get this file?
EDIT: The complete schema, to "calcfeatures Schema", from the link above looks like:
 <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2018/calcfeatures" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2018/calcfeatures" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" schemaLocation="xlbasictypes.xsd"/>
   <xsd:element name="calcFeatures" type="CT_CalcFeatures"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="CT_CalcFeatures">
     <xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:element name="feature" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="CT_CalcFeature"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="CT_CalcFeature">
     <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:schema>


I think you are hitting the Note ("If the ....xsd file is not valid XML, MSXML will ignore it and validate for well-formed XML only. To avoid this type of outcome, its a good practice to always validate your schema files first prior to attempting to use them in validation of other documents.") on Referencing XSD Schemas in Documents.

Wouldn't they be covered and pointed to in the relevant ECMA standard? Might want to check those and go from there

@RivenSkaye: I checked the ECMA-276, and could not find a reference to xlbasictype (, or xlbasictypes).

@RivenSkaye Did YOU check this standard to ensure there IS xlbasictypes.xsd? Whatta idiotic comments...

This question is similar to: Where to find Office 2007/2010/2013 Open XML Schemas. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JohnyL if I did, I'd have known whether or not is was there. It was merely a question to get some more context on the question because it's rather lacking in context of what you did or didn't do to find it. The question as you posted it is lacking in information that can be useful to help -- but by all means blame other people for probing for more info

Some digging around between official documentation, the ECMA specification, the various versions of the ISO/IEC documents and the MS docs on the OOXML SDK as well as through the very similar (probably an effective duplicate) question Robert Prévost mentioned quickly made it clear these XSD files are generated through the XSD and RNC files provided with part 4 of the ECMA standard and most likely included as assets in the OOXML SDK binary part.
There is, however, a website that links through the whole structure of it. Datypic through Schema Central. You'd be interested in the sml-* (SpreadsheetML) definitions. Specifically, the base types generated for .XL* files (spreadsheets)
